# cmd module - python

Tags: python, shell, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to build a python shell using cmd module.

```
from cmd import Cmd
import subprocess
import commands
import os 
from subprocess import call

class Pirate(Cmd): 
    intro = 'Welcome to shell\n'
    prompt = 'platform> '
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pirate().cmdloop()
```

I am trying to build a shell using python - cmd module. I am trying to build these two functionalities.

Welcome to shell

platform> ls

platform> cd ..

like if I want to perform 
ls - list all files from that directory in my python shell 
or 
cd .. - go back to prev directory

Can anyone help in this? 
I tried using subprocess library.. but didn't get it working.

Appreciate your help ! 
Ref Doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing it? I mean create new shell?

Comment: yeah.. for our project we will be automating few scripts through this.. I just wanted to try these before going to those

Comment: Did you try to use ipython with hooks?

Comment: Do you plan do reimplement all commands like `ls` and `cd` in Python or do you simply want to invoke the underlying system commands ?

Comment: Guillaume - Just I want to get a feel of how the python shell works and have the curiosity to try out these things.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time trying to figure out why you would need such a thing, but here's my attempt:

```
import subprocess
from cmd import Cmd

class Pirate(Cmd): 
    intro = 'Welcome to shell\n'
    prompt = 'platform> '

    def default(self, line): # this method will catch all commands
        subprocess.call(line, shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pirate().cmdloop()
```

The main point is to use `default` method to catch all commands passed as input.

Comment: can you tell me how it works with any system commands like ls / cd

Comment: Any command you pass as input (e.g. `ls -lh /`) will be passed to the `default(line)` method. `subprocess.call(line)` will simply invoke this command line (by starting the appropriate process with given arguments). If `ls` is in your PATH that will work.

Comment: I didnt get it working though :( I ran the program and tried ls inside python shell. 
platform> ls 
platform> cd .. 
didnt work out either

Answer (score -2):

```
def do_shell(self, line):
    "Run a shell command"
    print "running shell command:", line
    sub_cmd = subprocess.Popen(line,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = sub_cmd.communicate()[0]
    print output
    self.last_output = output
```

In command line:

```
(Cmd)!ls
(Cmd)!pwd
```

Comment: As it stands now, your answer is hard to read. Could you clean it up by formatting and indenting your code correctly? Also, it would help if you added some more text explaining how exactly your code works.